# multiple inheritance for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, multiple-inheritance

I want to create a multiple inheritance for a model.

in order to do that, I tried something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base, Devise::SessionsController
```

what is the way to do that correctly? I think my Syntax is not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby doesn't support multiple inheritance.  To share functionality between models, you want to use mixins.  Check out [this article](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_modules.html), particularly the section on mixins.

Comment: thank you, so should I do something like:
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
include Devise::SessionsController

Comment: Yes, and then if you have additional functionality that you want to include, you can add a line like `include MyAdditionalStuff` or `extend MyAdditionalStuff` inside your user class to add the MyAdditionalStuff module in.  Be sure to read up on the difference between `include` and `extend`.  Here is an overview - http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/ . If you don't already know the difference between instance and class methods, follow the link in the first paragraph FIRST.

Comment: this does not clearly define any way for the OP to solve their issue but instead mildly suggests they give up.  I am not down voting this answer at all.  It could just be a an upvoted AF comment